# Cast object to List<object>

Tags: c#

For some reasons outside of my control a method of mine needs to be defined to accept one parameter of type object. But i know that the value of this parameter is actually of type List with a generic parameter unknown to me.

I am trying to cast this object to List<object>, but have no idea how to do this without knowing what the exact generic parameter is.

I would like to do something like this:

```
public static List<object> ConvertToList(object input)
{
    if (input.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(List<>))) 
    {
        //Of course this does not work, because input might for example be of type List<string>
        return (List<object>) input;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I know that if I had `List<T>` instead of `object input`, it would be quite easy by using:

```
return input.Cast<object>()
```

but unfortunately i'm stuck with the object parameter. Any idea how i could solve this problem?

Comment: I don't think you can? A `List<SomeTypeHere>` and a `List<object>` are fundamentally different types, aren't they? (Genuinely asking - I'm not a C# expert). Where has your constraint come from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't cast it, but you can project it onto a list using `IEnumerable` and `Cast`. This will give you a new instance of `List<object>`. You won't be able to modify the old list but you can work with the new one and modify its elements.

```
object obj = new List<Whatever>();
List<object> list = ((IEnumerable)obj).Cast<object>().ToList();
```